# Proving Cauchy's theorem from Runge's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I want to show

> $\color{blue}{\text{Cauchy's Theorem}}$ *(homology version)*: Let $f:U\to \Bbb C$ be a holomorphic function and let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $U$. If the index of $\gamma$ is zero for every $a\in \Bbb C\setminus U$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz = 0$.

from

> $\color{blue}{\text{Runge's Theorem}}$: Any function holomorphic on a neighborhood of a compact set $K$ can be approximated uniformly on $K$ by rational functions whose singularities are in $\mathbb C\setminus K$.

---

**Question:**

My proof (below) works only if $U$ is simply-connected, which may not be true. How should I fix (rather, complete) my proof?

---

**My work:**
Let $f:U\to \Bbb C$ be a holomorphic function and let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $U$. Assume that the index of $\gamma$ is zero for every $a\in \Bbb C\setminus U$. There exists a compact set $K$, enclosing the curve $\gamma$. By Runge's theorem, there exists a sequence $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of rational functions (with singularities in $\mathbb C\setminus K$) converging uniformly to $f$ on $K$, and hence on $\gamma$. That is, $\|f - r_n\|_{\infty, K} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$. The norm is defined in the usual way, as $\|g\|_{\infty,K} := \sup_{z\in K} |g(z)|$. By uniform convergence of $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to $f$ on $\gamma$, we have $$\int_\gamma r_n \, dz \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \int_\gamma f(z)\, dz$$
Thus, it suffices to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\gamma r_n \, dz = 0$. Intuitively, I feel that $\int_\gamma r_n \, dz  = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, which would also ensure $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_\gamma r_n \, dz = 0$ as required. $r_n(z)$ is of the form $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ where $p,q$ are polynomials. Taking help of the partial fraction decomposition, it suffices to consider $q(z)$ of the form $q(z) = (z-b)^m$ for $b\in \mathbb C\setminus K$ and $m\in \mathbb N$. Since $b\in \mathbb C\setminus K$, $\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ is certainly holomorphic on $K$. By Cauchy's theorem (the usual version, i.e. $f$ holomorphic $\implies \int_\gamma f(z)\, dz = 0$ **if** $U$ is simply connected) we have $\int_\gamma r_n(z)\, dz = 0$, which completes the proof.

---

*Note*:
 1. The index of $\gamma$ (w.r.t. a point $a\in \Bbb C$) is denoted by $\operatorname{index}_a(\gamma)$ and defined as $$\operatorname{index}_a(\gamma):= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-a}$$
2. When I say "usual version" of Cauchy's theorem, I mean

> $\color{blue}{\text{Cauchy's Theorem}}$ *("usual" version)*: If $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected region $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz  = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$.

I am looking for a detailed proof/answer. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest that you add an exact quote of the “usual” version of Cauchy's theorem as well.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion, I have made the necessary edits.

Comment: Good. Now what is the “simply connected region” to which the theorem is applied at the end of your proof?

Comment: Hmm, I think my proof is incorrect - it doesn't work if $U$ is not simply connected. Right? @MartinR

Comment: That's what I think.

Comment: Assuming $U$ is open, then $U=\cup G$ where the members of $G$ are the $\subseteq$-maximal connected open subsets of $U$.  If $\gamma$ is a simple curve in $U$ then $\gamma\subset U'$ for some $U'\in G.$ And  $U'$ must be simply connected.

Comment: Why must $U'$ be simply connected? @DanielWainfleet

Comment: If $U'$ is open and connected but not simply connected then there will exist a point $a\not\in U$ and a simple closed curve $\gamma\subset U'$ such that the winding number (index) of $\gamma$ around $a$ is not $0$. I think this is intuitively clear, although a rigorous proof might need the Jordan Curve Theorem.